# File upload on android works only when using android's chrome dev tools?

Tags: android, node.js, express, file-upload, android-chrome

I wanted to share something that i found interesting and hopefully get an explanation of this behavior. It goes like this. I created a page and all it does is upload a file to the server.

```
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const file = input.files[0];

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:4000");

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(input.id, file);

  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
});
```

server

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const upload = require("express-fileupload");
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(cors());
app.use(upload());

const server = http.createServer(app).listen(4000);

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {

  fs.appendFile("./uploads/" + req.files.input.name, req.files.input.data,
    () => {
      res.send("file uploaded");
    }
  );
});
```

On pc it works just fine. Out of curiosity i wanted to test this on my android device. My pc is connected to mobile hotspot, and i go cmd>ipconfig to get ip adress. Now i enter the page on my phone and when i press upload nothing happens, file not added to folder on server. I think maybe onclick event listener doesn't work on android so i test it by removing http request and changing background color on press. It works. I decide to use USB debbuging so i can get to chrome dev tools on android. And then i try uploading again.

[image]

This time it works ! 
I think maybe it has something to do with phone now being connected to pc by usb. I exit android chrome dev tools and try uploading again, with usb connection. Again it does **NOT** work, file not added to folder on server. 
Does anyone have an idea why **ONLY** when using android dev tools does this work?

Comment: Where are you running your code: WebView, Chrome, Chrome Custom Tab?

Comment: I am using default chrome browser.